# TeamCity - How to create an installer package?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, nsis

I'm pretty new with *TeamCity* but have 2-3 years experience with *CC.NET*-t. I'm familiar with MSBuild but maybe *TeamCity* has other ways to build things.

I see that *TeamCity* has a nice UI and great plug-in framework. But I have no idea how can I configure an installer package build.

**My questions:**

- I've checked out the source and built the artifacts (some dll and exe). There is no problem, but
- **how** can I create a zip package "on *TeamCity* way"? (Project/artifact dependency?)
- **how** can I create a NSIS installer "on *TeamCity* way"?

Can I download plugins or tutorials? Or I have no other choice just MSBuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some [build runner plugins](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Build+Runner+Plugin) for TeamCity and you can roll your own but I believe the "TeamCity way" is to do that in your build script... since it's a build server right?

And you might want to check out the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack) which has a lot of nice-to-haves stuffs like **zipping** and **registry access** and whatnot... which will definitely help with those zip and nsis task.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to do this using your own handwritten build scripts.

MsBuild or NAnt will probably offer the best options for you.

If you use MsBuild you probably want to look at Msbuild community tasks.

Hope this helps